# Count how many rows are in sub_field

Tags: php, wordpress, count, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advanced custom field repeater to load some sub_fields which you can see in the below code:

```
<?php
    if( get_field('who_made_it') ): ?>
    <div id="role-wrapper">
        <?php while( has_sub_field('who_made_it') ): ?>
            <div class="role-item">
                <?php the_sub_field('job_role'); ?>
                <?php the_sub_field('description'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would like to count how many `.row-item`'s there are and then print that number as a class on the container `#role-wrapper` .

So as a HTML demo of how it would look:

```
<div id="role-wrapper" class"roleitems-3">
    <div class="role-item">
        content in here
    </div>
    <div class="role-item">
        content in here
    </div>
    <div class="role-item">
        content in here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified by [the docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), `get_field()` returns an `array()` of sub fields in this case. As a result, you can do a simple [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php):

```
<div id="role-wrapper" class"roleitems-<?php echo count( get_field('who_made_it') ); ?>">
```

Comment: How would I add the individual number count to each .role-item? So its role-item-1 role-item-2 role-item-3 etc

Comment: You'd use a counter, as suggested by @KnightHawk, and would `echo` the counter value on each item.

Answer (score 2):

I am unfamiliar with `has_sub_field` and the `advanced custom field repeater`, but it seems a simple answer would be to add a counter.

```
<?php 
$counter = 0;
while( has_sub_field('who_made_it') ):
    //do stuff
    $counter++;
endwhile;

//output the counter however you like
echo('<div class="counter">Total: ' . $counter . '</div>');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!