# Make first loop H1 tag and the remaining loop to H2 - PHP wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry, I'm just a complete novice in PHP

Background: This code is a loop of three slider as you can see here - http://rashelectrical.com.au/. I need to make the H1 tag only on the first slide and make the other two H2 tag

**Question:**

> How can I make the 2nd and last loop to H2 and H1 only on the first
>   loop?

Thanks

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/4jm5vhbf/

```
<?php while(have_rows('banner_slider')) : the_row();?>
<div class="sl" >
    <div class="header-content relative-block align-center text-center flex-container align-middle" style="background:url('<?php the_sub_field('image');?>') no-repeat">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="header-content-inner relative-block animate-children">
                    <h3><?php the_sub_field('subheading');?></h3>
                    <h1><?php the_sub_field('heading');?></h1>
                    <p><?php the_sub_field('description');?></p>
                    <div class="button-group align-center">
                        <?php $n = 1; while(have_rows('button_links')) : the_row(); 
                        $link_lr = get_sub_field('link');?>
                        <?php if($n == 2){
                          $n2 = 'hollow';
                        }else{
                          $n2 = '';
                        }?>
                          <a class="button <?php echo $n2; ?>" href="<?php echo $link_lr['url']; ?>"><span><?php echo $link_lr['title']; ?></span></a>
                        <?php    $n++; endwhile;?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: "Question: How can I make the 2nd and last loop and on the first loop?" I don't know what this means

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice the h1 and h2 tag disappeared. Already edited it. Will appreciate your help if you have the idea. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)? Could you show what result you expect from the code - sorry, but your problem description is not really understandable.

Comment: Yes, the site uses ACF. Please look at this part - http://prntscr.com/mqt1zk - on this site - http://rashelectrical.com.au/.

Comment: There are 3 slides there and what I am trying to achieve is I want the h1 element only on the first slide and the other 2 remaining slide to be h2 element

Comment: Right now, the 3 slides have H1 tag, but I want is only the first slide to have H1 tag

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda hard to tell without seeing the full code, maybe something like that?

```php
<!-- Instead of H3 tag here, use P tag with css class and change the font size with css -->
<h3><?php the_sub_field('subheading'); ?></h3>

<!-- count the heading elements -->
<?php $headings = count( get_sub_field( 'heading' ) ); ?>
<!-- Condition here if heading 1 echo H1 else echo H2 -->
<?php echo ($headings == 0) ? '<h1>' . the_sub_field('heading') . '</h1>' : '<h2>' . the_sub_field('heading') . '</h2>' ?>

<p><?php the_sub_field('description'); ?></p>

<!-- Your rest of code -->
```

Also for SEO and accessibility reasons, your HTML markup should considering the "Semantic" of your [Heading tags](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/headings/) .. so don't use H3 tag before H1 tag.

Comment: Thank you @awran, but it only counts 1 heading which results to display all heading tag in H1, also the heading text was displayed outside the H1 tag

Comment: I see you're using Slick slider to sliding your content and it seems that each slide has its own group of ACF fields so it will always count 1 field. Its really hard to tell without knowing how have you implemented these together. maybe try to add a counter like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380146/count-how-many-rows-are-in-sub-field)